# How to encode images with text as attributed strings

Tags: json, swift, nsuserdefaults, textkit

I am inserting images into a TextKit textView using an NSMutableAttributed string and NSAttachment with the following Swift imagePickerController code:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String, kUTTypeMovie as String]
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Insert Image", message: "Do you wish to insert the selected image?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
               
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Insert Image", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { [self]
                    (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
                attachment.image = pickedImage
                    
                    //save to app directory using this function below
                       saveImageToDocumentDirectory(image: pickedImage )
                    
                    //save to UserDefaults directory using this call below as alternate
                       let imageData:NSData = pickedImage.pngData()! as NSData
                     
                       UserDefaults.standard.set(imageData, forKey: "keyp2Image")
                  
                    let imageattributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
                    if let selectedRange = textView.selectedTextRange {
                        let cursorPosition = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)
                        
                        textView.textStorage.insert(imageattributedText, at:cursorPosition)
                        attrString.append(imageattributedText)
                        self.textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
                     
                            
                    }
                   
                   
        })
                let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: {
                    (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                    print("Cancel")
                })
             
               
                alert.addAction(cancelAction)
                alert.addAction(defaultAction)
               
                present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                
            }

    }
```

The above code saves images to either NSUserDefaults or to the application directory, however, my problem is I cannot get the saved images to reload using the following ViewDidLoad code snippet below:

```
 let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    if let savednotes = defaults.object(forKey: "newnotes") as? Data {
        let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

        do {
            notes = try jsonDecoder.decode([Note].self, from: savednotes)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to load notes")
        }
    }
  }
```

Question: What would the optimum method to reload both images and text simultaneously (text is reloading fine) using the above json decoder code. I have been banging on this for a while with not much success. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Why are you storing stuff like this into user defaults? You can simple convert that attributed string to an rtf file, and save it as a file instead. Loading the file would also become very simple. There's no need to save the image separately.

Answer (score 0):

`NSAttributedString` has methods that converts it to `Data` if you specify a format, and initialisers that take `Data` as parameters. You can then write that `Data` to a path you like. Your `Note` objects can then store `URL`s that point to the files. There are [many formats](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/documenttype) you can choose from. Choose one that supports attachments.

Here's how you would save and load `NSAttributedString`s to files:

```
// saving
let data = try attributedString.data(from: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length),
                                     documentAttributes: [.documentType:
                                                            NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtfd])
try data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: "some path"))

// loading
let dataRead = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "some path"))
let loadedAttributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: dataRead,
                                                options: [.documentType:
                                                            NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtfd],
                                                documentAttributes: nil)
```

Comment: This question was about saving and loading `NSAttributedString`s. Those seem to be separate problems. You should produce a [mcve] (not a download link) and post a new question. @user46938

Comment: Will repost an additional question with sample code!